# Hi I have a 1982 Honda magna motorcycle my rear wheel locked up while i was ridding

Tags: motorcycle, troubleshooting, repair, drive-shaft, diagnose

I have a 82 Honda Magna. I was riding down a hill and it just locked up on me. I skidded for about 5 feet and it wouldn’t budge. After yanking it back and forth for a while it broke free and I was able to move it a couple feet, after which it locked up again!

I was able to get it to a parking spot by violently humping the gas tank with my hips. The engine runs fine. The bike has shaft drive & drum brakes. The gears work, it just doesn’t move in neutral. I can get it move a little if you really really reef on it, but only a couple of inches. The only way to move it that I could find was a violent hip thrust to the gas tank. (I looked like a straight up crazy person because I was giving it to her.) There was no way I was just gonna leave my bike in the street and go home.

Anyway, does anybody have any experience with this, I am curious to know why it happens and most importantly I wanna know how to freakin fix it. [image: picture of similar bike]

Answer (score 3):

Something loose in gearbox that has allowed two pairs of gears to engage at the same time locking the box.
Or something jamming the output shaft.

Separate the output shaft from the gearbox and see if the rear wheel rotates, if still not, then it is something shaft or wheel related.

Trailer it home or to a garage and inspect it properly.

Comment: If the wheel doesn't spin after disengaging the shaft then it could be a seized rear wheel bearing.